# What's the most efficient way of traversing through all the adjacent cells of a particular cell in a 2D array?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to find out the adjacent cells of a cell **(i,j)**; which will be **(i,j+1)**, **(i,j-1)**, **(i-1,j)** and **(i+1,j**) in a 2D array.

*My code to implement this:*

```
for i in range(len(array)):

    for j in range(len(array)):

        if i==0:
            adjacent_row=[i,i+1]
        elif i==len(array)-1:
            adjacent_row=[i,i-1]
        else:
            adjacent_row=[i-1,i,i+1]

        if j==0:
            adjacent_column=[j]
        elif j==len(array)-1:                  # The column part is actually wrong, I don't know how to fix it
            adjacent_column=[j-1,j]
        else:
            adjacent_column=[j-1,j+1]

        for k in adjacent_row:

            for l in adjacent_column:

                #traverse through those cells
```

This was the idea that I had in my mind, but it's flawed.

Comment: What do you want to do when you "find" one?

Comment: How is this question related to the one that I am asking?

Comment: Because it could affect what the answer is (i.e. wrt "efficiency").

Answer (score 0):

For example you can do something like this

```
dx = [1,1,1,0,-1,-1,-1,0]
dy = [-1,0,1,1,1,0,-1,-1]
i = 2; j = 5 #The cell you want to have the neighbors
N = 10; M = 10 # Size of your array
neighbors = [] #Neighbors list
for x in dx:
    for y in dy:
        if i+x > 0 and i+x<N and j+y > 0 and j+y<M:
            neighbors.append(array[i+x,j+y])
```

Here I consider my array to be a numpy array but it don't change a lot of things